# execute a function based on specific times (in seconds) from an array

Tags: javascript

I want to execute `int` function based on specific times (in seconds) from the `times` array.

```
let times = [

    //[type, startTime, endTime]
    ['A', '2', '5'],
    ['B', '7', '9'],
    ['C', '12', '15'],

];


function int(startTime, endTime){

    console.log(startTime);
    console.log(endTime);

};
```

So we should execute the `int` function in seconds **2** , **7** and **12** (the second element in the inner arrays)

Note: we should be able to pass arrays to `times` array and the code should still work.

I have no idea if this is possible and need a hand to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this. The code should explain itself but if you have any questions let me know.

```js
let times = [

  //[type, startTime, endTime]
  ['A', '2', '5'],
  ['B', '7', '9'],
  ['C', '12', '15'],

];


function int(startTime, endTime) {
  console.log(startTime);
  console.log(endTime);
};

times.forEach((elem)=> {
  setTimeout(() => {
    int(elem[1], elem[2]); // Call to function
  }, elem[1] * 1000); // Conversion to seconds
});
```

Comment: I didn't know that in each iteration a new instance of setTimeout would be created! Correct me if I'm wrong..